# How to make Jackson cast all map-like nodes to my custom class during deserialization?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class implementing `Map<String, Object>` interface:

```
public class TypedObject implements Map<String, Object>, Serializable {...}
```

An instance of `TypedObject` may contain another instance of `TypedObject` as value and so on.

By default, Jackson's `ObjectMapper` deserializes any map-like records to `LinkedHashMap`. I want it to deserialize any sub-map to `TypedObject`.

I know that I can implement my own deserializer, but it seems to me that there's a much simpler way.

So how can I inform `ObjectMapper` of what I want?

**Example:**

```
{"child":{"name":"son","child":{"name":"grandson"}}}
```

should be deserialized to `TypedObject`, which contains another `TypedObject` value, which also contains a `TypedObject` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to specify mapping from abstract type `Map` into `TypedObject`. This can be done by constructing `SimpleModule`, calling its "addAbstractTypeMapping(...)" method, registering module with `ObjectMapper`.

For this to work, `TypedObject` must have a zero-argument constructor available.

Comment: Your approach didn't work for me and I even added some comments about it here. And suddenly I realized that I'm using old version of jackson libs. After updating to last version it works. Sorry for my disbelief.

Comment: Ok good that it works with a recent version. There may well have been some gaps, with some deserializers skipping checks for actual implementation to use.

Comment: @StaxMan I've tried to do so, but it only works for the highest level map, all of the sub-maps are still LinkedHashMaps

Comment: @blumonk if this is happening with Jackson 2.6, please file an issue for `jackson-databind`. All instances of `Map` and `Object` should be deserialized into appropriate mapped overrides.